# httpx python request to webpage wont redirect

Tags: python, python-requests, httpx

Currently making a request to a webpage which redirects a user to another URL (after a few seconds) but my httpx request doesn't follow this redirect, it just stops after it has made the request to the original URL. I am using the `follow redirects` kwarg, which statesd that it should be redirected, but this doesn't work. `print(request)` outputs `none`.

I'm unsure how I can fix this?

```py
import httpx
client = httpx.Client(follow_redirects=True)
request = client.build_request("GET", "example...")
while request is not None:
    response = client.send(request)
    request = response.next_request
    print(request)
```

Comment: Same problem here... :(

Comment: How does the target website redirects you? Using HTTP code 301/302, or through some JS trickery? `follow_redirects` only works with HTTP 301/302.

Comment: Hey @pepoluan, the website redirects with javascript trickery!